# Merge 2 datatables in Javascript

Tags: javascript, highcharts, datatables

In c#, i can use `dtOne.Merge(dtTwo);` to merge 2 datatables.

Am having 2 datatables.

```
$('#table1').dataTable();

$('#table2').dataTable();
```

How to do this opeartion table1 = table1 + table2 ???

ie How can I merge them into a single datatable using javascript?

Comment: what you want to merge.?

Comment: I have tried using var dtable3 = dtable1.concat(dtable2) .. But that dint work..

Comment: so, i think first of all: you want to merge the actual data of your datatable, don't you? Then it's a question of how this data is delivered... serverside? clientside? which protocol... json, probably? At least, we need (much) more details to create a correct answer... i can just guess you search s.th. like `oTable.fnGetData();` where oTable = `$('#table1').dataTable()` and then you got your array and do the same with the second datatable and concatenate the arrays. but as said, this is just a guess ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Datatable class is directly not available in javascript. You can merge two data collection using following methods:

1) You can merge array data using following syntax:

```
var newArray = $.merge([], oldArray);
```

Example: Merges two arrays, altering the first argument.

```
$.merge( [ 0, 1, 2 ], [ 2, 3, 4 ] )
```

Result:
[ 0, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4 ]

2) You also merge two JSON objects using following syntax:

```
var object = $.extend({}, object1, object2);
```